# Xamarin Disable Broadcast Receiver

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am looking to disable a broadcast receiver I have attached to the boot_completed action. The receiver works as expected however I am looking to disable this receiver when the user disables my updater as detailed towards the bottom of https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html.

The code I am trying to use to do this is:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, "com.app.bootcompleted");
PackageManager pm = context.PackageManager;
pm.SetComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DontKillApp);
```

However PackageManager does not contain: **COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED**

Is there a different way to disable a broadcast receiver in **Xamarin Android**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the documentation is out of date https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting/

I have managed to enable/ disable the boradcast receiver by using the following piece of code:

```
//Stop the boot_complete receiver from starting the alarm
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, "com.app.bootCompleteReceiver");
PackageManager pm = context.PackageManager;
pm.SetComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, ComponentEnabledState.Disabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);
```

Also to make sure to decorate the Broadcast receiver correctly:

```
[BroadcastReceiver (Name = "com.app.bootCompleteReceiver", Enabled = false)]
public class BootCompleteReceiver : BroadcastReceiver { ...
```